Is it possible to change the "update" authority of an SPL token?
I have an SPL token and I'd like to change the "update authority" of that token. I am NOT using the Token-2022 standard.
This SPL token has the mint, free & metadata authorities revoked.
I have tried the CLI, as follows: spl-token authorize (owner/metadata) ...
But it said the SPL token doesn't support it.
Is it possible to change the "update authority"?

Does this answer your question? How to give up metadata update permission for spl token via solana api?
